# integer list of rgb to image python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

So I have a list of integer r,g,b ,r,g,b ,r ,g,b ,...

```
[255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255]
```

I also have a size of image width: 4 and height: 4  of the image

So how can I use the library Pil to show the image

(note: I may have a longer list width and height)

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this,

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pixels =[255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 127, 0, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255, 0, 127, 255]
image_out = Image.new(mode = "RGB", size = (200, 200))
image_out.putdata(pixels)
image_out.save('test_out.png')
```

If you want to show your image, this should do it:

```
image_out.show()
```

It's all in the documentation, go check it out for more.
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html

**Using 4x4 pixels & converting to 200x200**

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pixels =[(255,0,0),(255,0,0),(255,0,0),(255,0,0),(127,0,255),(127,0,255),(127,0,255),(127,0,255),(127,0,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255),(0,127,255)]
image_out = Image.new("RGB",(4,4))
image_out.putdata(pixels)
image_out.save('test_out.png')
#
img = image_out.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('testtest.png')
```

Initial 4x4 image gives (test_out.png):

[image]

Resized 200x200 image gives (testtest.png):

[image]

Comment: how can we convert width 4 pixel and height 4 pixel into 200x 200? The image is all black, I think something happen with it

Comment: Firstly, the list of pixels you provided is definitely more than a 4x4. Secondly, if you want to resize your image, you can use `image_out.resize((desiredwidth,desiredheight), Image.ANTIALIAS)`. This will convert your ORIGINAL image size to whatever specified.

Comment: (255,0,0)(255,0,0)(255,0,0)(255,0,0) (127,0,255)(127,0,255)(127,0,255)(127,0,255) (127,0,255)(0,127,255)(0,127,255)(0,127,255)(0,127,255)(0,127,255)(0,127,255)(0,127,255)

Comment: the image output is something like this, little tiny https://imgur.com/a/N6633b1

Comment: total 16 pixel = 4 x4

Comment: Done. Check my edits. The only difference is how the pixels are added, with brackets.